# unable to load a local js file in react component ( Using React-Biolerplate )

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

**What i am trying to do:**
Adding `vidyoConnector.js` script to a react component in order to create a `WebRTC` instance with vidyo.

**What is happening:**
Instead of adding the particular `vidyoConnector.js` it loads `index.html` because of which i get an **unexpected token error** in console.

I am using `react-async-script-loader` to load this vidyoConnector script.
Also tried to add the script using **Weback addAssetPlugin** but ended up breaking the Build.

**What i am expecting :**
Any best approach to load a library file into the component which has its dependency.

Note - The Vidyo library has been written in `jquery` and hence do not support the ES6 modular pattern.

Please help me with any best approach to achieve the same.

```
import React from "react";
import { FormattedMessage } from "react-intl";
import scriptLoader from "react-async-script-loader";
import messages from "./messages";
import $ from "jquery";

class HomePage extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      const webrtcLogLevel = "&webrtcLogLevel=info";
      const webrtc = true;
      const plugin = false;

      script.src = "https://static.vidyo.io/4.1.15.7/javascript/VidyoClient/VidyoClient.js?onload=onVidyoClientLoaded&webrtc=" +
  webrtc +
  "&plugin=" +
  plugin +
  webrtcLogLevel;
script.async = true;

script.onload = () => {
  VidyoClientInitialize($);
  console.log(VC);
};

   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

render() {
   return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          <FormattedMessage {...messages.header} />
        </h1>
        <button onClick={this.joinCall}>Connect</button>
         <div id="renderer" />
       </div>
      );
   }

  onVidyoClientLoaded(status) {
     console.log(
         "Status: " + status.state + "Description: " + status.description
     );
     switch (status.state) {
         case "READY": // The library is operating normally
             $("#connectionStatus").html("Ready to Connect");
             $("#helper").addClass("hidden");
             StartVidyoConnector(VC, VCUtils.params.webrtc);
           break;
         case "RETRYING": 
             $("#connectionStatus").html(
      "Temporarily unavailable retrying in " +
        status.nextTimeout / 1000 +
        " seconds"
    );
    break;
  case "FAILED": // The library operating has stopped
    ShowFailed(status);
    $("#connectionStatus").html("Failed: " + status.description);
    break;
  case "FAILEDVERSION": // The library operating has stopped
    UpdateHelperPaths(status);
    ShowFailedVersion(status);
    $("#connectionStatus").html("Failed: " + status.description);
    break;
  case "NOTAVAILABLE": // The library is not available
    UpdateHelperPaths(status);
    $("#connectionStatus").html(status.description);
    break;
  }
  return true;
}

joinCall() {
  vidyoConnector.Connect({
  host: "prod.vidyo.io", 
  token: "XXXX", 
  displayName: "Sachin", 
  resourceId: "demoRoom", 
  onSuccess: function() {
    console.log("Connected!! YAY!");
  },
  onFailure: function(reason) {
    console.error("Connection failed");
  },
  onDisconnected: function(reason) {
    console.log(" disconnected - " + reason);
  }
 });
 }
}

export default scriptLoader([
  "./vidyoConnector.js",
])(HomePage);
```

[console view of loaded js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8z7a.png)

Comment: Where is index.html coming from? Do you have index.html defined in your project? Also, make sure that "onVidyoClientLoaded" is defined before "VidyoClient.js" is loaded. Basically the onload call back has to be defined.

Comment: @SachinHegde i have index.html in the root path ( app/index.html) and i am trying to load the vidyoCOnnector.js which doest seems to load as a js file instead loads the index.html itself. this is my issue. The vidyoClient which i am loading over vidyo domain works fine but the vidyoconnector.js in my local does'nt load.